# API responds with Bad Request Error message

Tags: python

Could someone take a look at this code and let me know if there's something I'm doing wrong:

```
import requests

url = "https://api-end-point"

payload = {"grant_type": "client_credentials", "client_id":"my_ic", "client_secret": "not_now_please"}
headers = '{"accept": "application/json", "content-type": "application/json"}'

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

For some reason it's throwing error.

```
{"type":"http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html","title":"Bad Request","status":400,"detail":"JSON decoding error: Syntax error, malformed JSON"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first use `json` instead of `data`, second don't use `'` around the `headers`, or actually you don't need to specify `headers`:

```
import requests

url = "https://api-end-point"

payload = {"grant_type": "client_credentials", "client_id":"my_ic", "client_secret": "not_now_please"}

response = requests.request("POST", url, json=payload)

print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

The page does not contain `json/application` but `html/text`. If you remove the headers then it works:

```
response = requests.request(method="POST", url=url, data=payload)
```

If you have special needs to specify in the headers add details to your question